# Nginx Rails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

When I start nginx, I get this error:

```
Preloader for /u/apps/Dismissrr/current started on PID 23521, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.23443/generation-0/backends/preloader.23521
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9237 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr] [ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9235 23559/0x0000000664d420(Worker 1) utils.rb:55 ]: *** Exception SocketError in Rack application object (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known) (process 23559, thread 0x0000000664d420(Worker 1)):
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9240 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gelf-1.3.2/lib/gelf/ruby_sender.rb:16:in `send'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9241 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gelf-1.3.2/lib/gelf/ruby_sender.rb:16:in `block in send_datagrams'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9242 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gelf-1.3.2/lib/gelf/ruby_sender.rb:15:in `each'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9243 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gelf-1.3.2/lib/gelf/ruby_sender.rb:15:in `send_datagrams'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9245 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gelf-1.3.2/lib/gelf/notifier.rb:143:in `notify_with_level!'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9246 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gelf-1.3.2/lib/gelf/notifier.rb:131:in `notify_with_level'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9247 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gelf-1.3.2/lib/gelf/logger.rb:25:in `add'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9248 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gelf-1.3.2/lib/gelf/logger.rb:33:in `info'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9249 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/releases/20130405020833/config/initializers/graylog.rb:13:in `block in method_missing'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9250 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/releases/20130405020833/config/initializers/graylog.rb:13:in `each'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9251 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/releases/20130405020833/config/initializers/graylog.rb:13:in `method_missing'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9252 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:31:in `call_app'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9253 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:18:in `call'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9254 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9256 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9257 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9258 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9259 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9260 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.3/lib/rack/ssl.rb:27:in `call'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9261 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9262 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9263 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9264 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9265 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9266 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9267 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9268 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /u/apps/Dismissrr/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9269 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/passenger-enterprise-server-4.0.0.rc5/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:56:in `process_request'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9270 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/passenger-enterprise-server-4.0.0.rc5/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:119:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9271 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/passenger-enterprise-server-4.0.0.rc5/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:90:in `main_loop'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9272 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/passenger-enterprise-server-4.0.0.rc5/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:463:in `block (4 levels) in start_threads'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9273 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/passenger-enterprise-server-4.0.0.rc5/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/robust_interruption.rb:102:in `disable_interruptions'
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9274 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr]   from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/passenger-enterprise-server-4.0.0.rc5/lib/phusion_pa
[ 2013-04-05 03:16:30.9276 23447/7fb12e117700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1144 ]: [App 23521 stderr] ssenger/request_handler.rb:458:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
2013/04/05 03:16:30 [error] 23462#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 206.205.249.126, server: demo.dismissrr.com, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "demo.dismissrr.com"
```

The server_name in my config is "demo.dismissrr.com"

Why could this happening?

I'm using:

- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.13
- Passenger Enterprise 4.0.0 revision 5

Comment: Refer these: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235168/passenger-nginx-502-bad-gateway-errors-in-production# 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441118/passenger-3-0-17-nginx-1-2-4-content-length-header-502-bad-gateway# 3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250138/nginx-passenger-rails-3-1-502-bad-gateway#. It may help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getaddrinfo is likely telling you that it's unable to resolve a DNS name.  May need a static /etc/hosts mapping or to fix some DNS somewhere.  Knowing you though, you've already figured it out by now :)   Good to hear from you, Mr. Baumgarten.